# Include PHP file in joomla template

Tags: php, joomla

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('position-7')): ?>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">  <a href="#" > Home </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="<?php include_once('templates/'.$this->template.'../test.php'); ?>"> page </a></li>

        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-7" style="none" />
  </div>

</nav>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am new in joomla template edit index.php file and added the menu and insert external php file test.php

trying this way getting on error.

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /joomla_site/ï»¿test my code on this server.
Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: And do you have the permission? Does the file exists?

Comment: no just include index.php template file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you're doing with external PHP files. ?

you need to create some menu items right ?
first you have login  to admin section and add some menu types and menu items.
the check the site front end it will shows there. If you need some custom styles and all simply add extra classes on the menu item adding section.

you need a separate menu section than Joomla already have, simply [create a module](http://www.walkswithme.net/joomla-module-development-tutorial) and assign that to a position , read the menu items from DB inside the module instead of including php file.

Joomla already have a module for rendering menu items you can reuse that.

hope its make sense..

do some research before doing mixing core php with joomla.

Comment: yes you are a right  but I am logged in  admin to create menu then how to add php file in this menu because give some form details

Comment: not able to add php files to menu. you have menu items right add it under a menu type. using module you can render it any where.

Comment: can't not see which module will added in menu item type